# File Modes in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I am trying to make a database sort of thing but my r+, w+ and a+ are not working I have to close the file and opening again in different mode to perform every operation. This is the code that works but when I write the same with just one file object and mode as r+ or w+ or rw+ or r+w and the same combinations of r and a it doesn't print. It just writes to the file but doesn't print the lines.

```
import os;
import sys;

def fileInput(numOfEmployees):
    for i in range(numOfEmployees):
        empId, empFName, empLName, empSalary,  empEmailId = raw_input("Enter employee id: "), raw_input("Enter employee first name: "), raw_input("Enter employee last name: "), raw_input("Enter employee salary: "), raw_input("Enter employee Email ID: ");
        string = empId+" "+empFName+" "+empLName+" "+empSalary+" "+empEmailId+"\n";
        fw.write(string);

def fileSearch(searchStr, fr):
    line = fr.readline();
    while line:
        empId, empFName, empLName, empSalary,  empEmailId = line.split();
        if(searchStr == empFName):
            print line;
        line = fr.readline();


def main():
    numOfEmployees = input("Enter the number of employees: ");
    fileInput(numOfEmployees);
    fw.close();
    searchStr = raw_input("Enter the name of the employee you want to search: ");
    fr = open(string, "r");
    fileSearch(searchStr, fr);
    fr.close();
try:
    string = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"/FileIO.txt";
    fw = open(string, "w");
    main();
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    fr.close();
    fw.close();
    sys.exit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) if you use a single filehandle(eg: fw or fr) remember when you read a file, the cursor moves down the file. You'll have to 'scroll the cursor back' to the top (see `seek`)

2) the 'rw' will overwrite the previous file, deleting the previous entries from the last run. use 'a+'

try this:

```
import os;
import sys;

FileName='FileIO.txt'

def fileInput(fw,numOfEmployees):
    for i in range(numOfEmployees):
        empId, empFName, empLName, empSalary,  empEmailId = raw_input("Enter employee id: "), raw_input("Enter employee first name: "), raw_input("Enter employee last name: "), raw_input("Enter employee salary: "), raw_input("Enter employee Email ID: ");
        string = empId+" "+empFName+" "+empLName+" "+empSalary+" "+empEmailId+"\n";
        fw.write(string);

def fileSearch(fw, searchStr):
    line = fw.readline();
    while line:
        empId, empFName, empLName, empSalary,  empEmailId = line.split();
        if(searchStr == empFName):
            print line;
        line = fw.readline();


def main():

    string = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/'+FileName;

    try:
        fw = open(string, "a+");
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()

    numOfEmployees = input("Enter the number of employees: ");
    fileInput(fw,numOfEmployees);

    searchStr = raw_input("Enter the name of the employee you want to search: ");
    fw.seek(0)
    fileSearch(fw,searchStr);

    fw.close();

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: But now I again want to suppose edit a line or delete it so how can it be done in append mode.